# Storing Visual Studio Solution with multiple projects in SVN

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control, visualsvn

I am having a hard time adding a Visual Studio Solution with multiple projects to my repo. I am using VisualSVN. Here is my directory structure

```
c:\-----
    |
    ---Projects
           |
           --MyApp
              |
              ---Project1 (The solution is in this project directory)
              ---Project2
              ---Project3
```

When I select "MyApp" as the working copy root, nothing is added. If I select one of the project folder, only 2 are added.

Comment: http://amadiere.com/blog/2009/06/multiple-subversion-projects-in-one-visual-studio-solution-using-svnexternals/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the structure I use with success:

```
dev
 |- Project root folder (solution file here is the key)
    |- Class Project
    |- Class Project
    |- Web Project
    |- References
    |- Resources
```

What I'm suggesting is that you should move your .sln file to the top level then import.

Answer (score 0):

Another advance approach. 
Each project has it is own trunk with following structure

```
trunk
  |- .sln
  |- src
    |- ClassProject
    |- Web Project
```

Then in a separate svn directory create sub directory for every solution you need. For example you can have AllProjects, WebOnly, DALOnly. 
And using svn:externals bring every project you need (ClassProject etc.) in given case.